# Trying to pass new data to an object without replacing old data in mongoDB from nodejs with express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I am trying to pass new data to an object without replacing the old data using nodejs. My Mongodb database (before adding new data) structure is below

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58fd05f7fb69f42d54fccd12"),
"Transaction" : {
    "QRIDNumber6666" : {
        "retailer" : "watson",
        "discount" : "10%",
        "tax" : "5%",
        "Transaction Detail" : [ 
            {
                "quantity" : "1",
                "pname" : "coca",
                "price" : "3"
            }, 
            {
                "quantity" : "3",
                "pname" : "pepsi",
                "price" : "5"
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

What i want to achieve is to add another QRIDNumber under Transaction, Ex: QRIDNumber 7777, which has different values but the same structure when compared to QRIDNumber6666

My current attempt is by using the following code on nodejs

```
app.put('/contactlist/', function (req, res) {
var id = "58fd05f7fb69f42d54fccd12";
db.CollectionName.findAndModify({
query: {_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)},
update: {$set: {Transaction: req.body}},
new: true});
});
```

Note: req.body is the details and values of QRIDNumber7777 that is to be sent from my controller.

The end result from my code was it just replaced all previous content under "Transaction" (QRIDNumber6666) and replaced it with only new content(QRIDNumber7777).

I wish to have both data remain. Adding new contents under "Transaction" without deleting old ones

Comment: If the new QRID is guaranteed to be new could you use dot notation in your query so you arent replacing the whole object? `update: {$set: {[\`Transaction.${req.body.id}\`]: req.body}},`

Comment: i've thought of it but the problem is that the QRIDNumber(id) will mostly not be known as the values will of QRIDNumber will be dynamic and incremental rather then just QRIDNumber 6666 and QRIDNumber 7777.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so assuming you'll always have an object with 1 key in `req.body`. Like:

`req.body = {"QRIDNumber7777": {...}}`

First, you need to know the name of the key:

```
const insertedTransactionName = Object.keys(req.body)[0]; // QRIDNumber7777
```

Now you can update your document without overwriting other fields.

```
app.put('/contactlist/', function(req, res) {
    var id = "58fd05f7fb69f42d54fccd12";
    db.CollectionName.findAndModify({
        query: {
            _id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)
        },
        update: {
            $set: {
                [`Transaction.${insertedTransactionName}`]: req.body[insertedTransactionName]
            }
        },
        new: true
    });
});
```

Note this line:

```
$set: {
    [`Transaction.${insertedTransactionName}`]: req.body[insertedTransactionName]
}
```

Instead of overwriting whole `Transaction` document, you update only one nested property. So `QRIDNumber6666` data still remains.

Comment: Thanks, although in my case, i won't know the name of the key, the QRIDNumber is actually to be automatically generated by my QR Code Generator, although i think i can working around it is possible! thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should update your structure to `Transaction` array instead of creating dynamic keys.

This will help you later when you want to update the individual fields by referencing using positional operator.

So you should change your structure to

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58fd05f7fb69f42d54fccd12"),
"Transaction" : [{
        "QRIDNumber": 6666,
        "retailer" : "watson",
        "discount" : "10%",
        "tax" : "5%",
        "Transaction Detail" : [ 
            {
                "quantity" : "1",
                "pname" : "coca",
                "price" : "3"
            }, 
            {
                "quantity" : "3",
                "pname" : "pepsi",
                "price" : "5"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Use `$push` to add the new entry 7777 into `Transaction` array.

```
app.put('/contactlist/', function (req, res) {
var id = "58fd05f7fb69f42d54fccd12";
db.CollectionName.findAndModify({
query: {_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)},
update: {$push: {Transaction: req.body}},
new: true});
});
```